# user and usermeta table not found

Tags: users, login, user-meta

after couple months i tried to login into my website.
But I noticed even after entering correct details I was not able to login.
So I thought of resetting password and it also failed because of email id not found error.

Finally I decided to manually reset password from phpmyadmin.

When I opened it I can't find user and usermeta table.

I don't know how it happened or my db was hacked.

My prefix is main so I can't fine main_user and main_usermeta

I was running multisite.

I can't login to any site.

Please help me.

How add myself as admin again so that I can add users.

I don't have backup of my db.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to try following:

1. Create a separate clean install of multisite
2. Move user tables from it to your site

I vaguely remember encountering situation like this before, but not what the outcome was.

Also backup *current* state immediately, so at least you have that captured, in case you make things worse while attempting a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Add [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/#installing) to your server.

Create a new user.

```
wp user create foo foo@example.com --role=administrator --user_pass=password
```

Add `foo` as a super admin.

```
wp super-admin add foo
```

Login with `foo`:`password`.